# Accessing contact info from iphone contact app

Tags: ios, iphone

My app uses phone contact information to identify the sender of a message.

I have the following questions:

1)Is it allowed for an app to ask user during first use "This App would like to access your contacts"?

2) I am not sure how WhatsApp messaging works but it is allowed to find out that which contact is using whats app. Any idea how this works?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes it is allowed, and it is automatically asked for you when you access the iOS Address Book APIs.
2. WhatsApp knows your own contact info, so it sends it to it's servers, then keeps a database of all users that are using it's service. Then it compares your contact list against it's database of known users.